# \listoffigures by chapter and sections

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to make a list of figures but I want it to do it in sections. Anyone knows how to do it? I tried to do something with `\renewcommand` but I couldn't.

Comment: Do you want one list of figures with gaps between sections, section numbers as part of the figure number, or a separate list of figures in each section?  All of these are possible.  See also the multitoc package.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I need to have a list of figures at the end of the document, but each section has its proper numeration figure, that's why I need to separate the list in parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the `titletoc` package. This template will help you get started.

In the example there are 5 tables and 6 figures distributed in three sections of a chapter.

The local lists of tables and list of figures will be generated for the chapter and also for each individual section.

The collection of elements (figures or tables) is activated  with `\startlist[<local name>]{<lof or lot>}` and it is ended with a  `\stoplist[<local name>]{<lof or lot>}`.

The collected list can be printed with  `\printlist[<local name>]{<lof or lot>}{}{}`.

It must be compiled at least twice for the parcial lof or toc appears.

[image: a]

[image: b]

This is the complete code.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{titletoc} % needed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% only for dummy text 

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}

% start  local list tables and figures for chapter
\startlist[localchaplot]{lot}
\startlist[localchaplof]{lof}

% print the list
\printlist[localchaplot]{lot}{}{}   
\printlist[localchaplof]{lof}{}{}

\bigskip

1. \kant[1]

\newpage 
\section{One}

% start  local list tables and figures for section
\startlist[localseclot]{lot}
\startlist[localseclof]{lof}


\printlist[localseclot]{lot}{}{}    
\printlist[localseclof]{lof}{}{}
\bigskip

% start section content
2. \kant[2]
\begin{table}[ht!]\caption{table 1 sec One}\end{table}
\begin{table}[ht!]\caption{table 2 sec One}\end{table}
\begin{table}[ht!]\caption{table 3 sec One}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[ht!]\caption{figure 1 sec One}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht!]\caption{figure 2 sec One}\end{figure}
% end section content

% stop the local list for section
\stoplist[localseclot]{lot}
\stoplist[localseclof]{lof}

\newpage    
\section{Two}
\startlist[localseclot]{lot}
\startlist[localseclof]{lof}

\printlist[localseclot]{lot}{}{}    
\printlist[localseclof]{lof}{}{}
\bigskip

% start section content
3. \kant[3]
\begin{table}[ht!]\caption{table 4 sec Two}\end{table}  
\begin{figure}[ht!]\caption{figure 3 sec Two}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht!]\caption{figure 4 sec Two}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht!]\caption{figure 5 sec Two}\end{figure}
% end section content

\stoplist[localseclot]{lot}
\stoplist[localseclof]{lof}

\newpage
\section{Three}
\startlist[localseclot]{lot}
\startlist[localseclof]{lof}

\printlist[localseclot]{lot}{}{}    
\printlist[localseclof]{lof}{}{}
\bigskip

4. \kant[4]
\begin{table}[ht!]\caption{table 5 sec Three}\end{table}    
\begin{figure}[ht!]\caption{figure 6 sec Three}\end{figure}

\stoplist[localseclot]{lot}
\stoplist[localseclof]{lof}

% stop the local list for chapter
\stoplist[localchaplot]{lot}
\stoplist[localchaplof]{lof}
% chapter ends 


\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked, but I don't know since my documentclass is amsbook, the on the list doesn't appear "Fig. 1", just appear "1.".

Comment: @Merder This site works best one question at a time, so other readers can benefit.

If you think my answer to your question as worded helps you, please accept it by ticking the green tick to the left of the answer.

Formatting the amsbook table of contents is a different topic, so you'd better ask another question. There are other similar questions on this topic on this site. I will be happy to help.